# LiveData does not emit required value

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have my live data created like this:

```
val authTokenLiveData: LiveData<String?> = liveData {
    emit(accountManager.myAuthToken())
}
```

And I am observing it like it:

```
accountViewModel.authTokenLiveData.observe(this) {
    toast("Token is $it")
    if(it == null) goToLogin()
}
```

It works well at first, I get the token toasted, however when I logout, and hence remove the token such that the token is `null`, I do not go to login which I should according to my observer.

How do I ensure that the `authTokenLiveData` emits `null` when the token becomes `null` so that my observer allows me to go to the login screen?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer here is "You can't". The `liveData` builder runs once. After the first emit it will not emit again when the source changes.

I had to manually go to the login screen without observing `authTokenLiveData`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these answers overcomplicate the problem here in my opinion. I would suggest creating a sealed class to manage the state of your users login. Here is an example:

*Create a sealed class to manage your logged in state:*

```
sealed class LoggedInState {
class LoggedIn(token: String) : LoggedInState()
class LoggedOut() : LoggedInState()
}
```

In your ViewModel, emit that state (I would prefer that the AccountManager handles this code and returns the LoginState rather than the token, but this is just for example):

```
val authTokenLiveData: LiveData<LoggedInState> = liveData(Dispatched.IO) {
    val token = accountManager.myAuthToken()
    val state = if (token.isNullOrEmpty()) LoggedOut() else LoggedIn(token)
    emit(state)
}
```

Then observe this state in your activity / fragment and handle each case:
*Activity*

```
accountViewModel.authTokenLiveData.observe(this) {
    when (state) {
        is LoggedIn -> toast("Token is ${state.token}")
        is LoggedOut -> goToLogin()
    }
}
```

*Fragment*

```
accountViewModel.authTokenLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    when (state) {
        is LoggedIn -> toast("Token is ${state.token}")
        is LoggedOut -> goToLogin()
    }
}
```

Note: please excuse any typos, I typed this out on my phone

Answer (score 0):

```
   // LiveData object is usually stored within a ViewModel 
    val currentName: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }


   // updating the live data object 
   // using setValue(T) or postValue(T)
   button.setOnClickListener {
          val anotherName = "John Doe"
          model.currentName.setValue(anotherName)
      }

  // Observe LiveData Object
  // Use the 'by viewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
  // from the activity-ktx artifact
private val model: NameViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Other code to setup the activity...

    // Create the observer which updates the UI.
    val nameObserver = Observer<String> { newName ->
        // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
        nameTextView.text = newName
    }

    // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
    model.currentName.observe(this, nameObserver)
}
```

Comment: No, this can not work. The live data is comming from AccountManager. I have to observe the data in AccountManager not set the live data myself

Answer (score 0):

Create your `LiveData` in your `ViewModel` like:

```
val authToken: MutableLiveData<String?> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<String?>()
}
```

Observe the `LiveData` from your `Activity` like:

```
viewModel.authToken.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    toast("Token is $it")
    if(it == null) goToLogin()
})
```

Observe the `LiveData` from your `Fragment` like:

```
viewModel.authToken.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    toast("Token is $it")
    if(it == null) goToLogin()
})
```

Pass your `ViewModel` to your `AccountManager`. Then post data to that `LiveData` from your `AccountManager` like:

```
viewModel.authToken.postValue("Authorization Token")
```

You will get the latest data to your observer block.

Comment: The auth Token is coming from AccountManager. I need to observe the data in AccountManager, how do I do that

Comment: @Ssenyonjo See I updated the answer. You should pass your `ViewModel` to your `AccountManager` then you set value to your `LiveData` from your `AccountManager`.

Answer (score 0):

it's better practice to observe the token at the Activity direct from the `AccountManager` object instead from the ViewModel (this way you are not bound to one activity). few things to consider:

1. Make sure `AccountManager` is a Singleton object.
2. Use a `MutableLiveData` for the token. usage can be done like this (at the `AccountManager`):

   ```
   private val _cachedToken = MutableLiveData<AuthToken?>()

   val cachedToken: LiveData<AuthToken?>
       get() = _cachedToken

   fun setValue(newValue: AuthToken?) {
       GlobalScope.launch(Main) {
           if (_cachedToken.value != newValue) {
               _cachedToken.value = newValue
           }
       }
    }
   ```
3. keep reference of `accountManager` at your different Activities and call from there to `setValue()` to change the state (better to separate it to methods of `login()` and `logout()` ):

   ```
   logout_button.setOnClickListener{
       accountManager.logout() // this is finally setting the LiveData obj to null
   }


   accountManager.cachedToken.observe(this, { authToken ->
       if(authToken == null) {
           navAuthActivity()
       }
   })
   ```
4. You are using a non-nullable observer.
   Please try changing the `observe` constructor (like I did above) to:

   ```
   accountViewModel.authTokenLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
       toast("Token is $it")
       if(it == null) goToLogin()
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Emitting `liveData{}` builder didn't work for me.
Using a lazily `MutableLiveData` field emits unnecessary initial value (probably when it's first time accessed).

What worked for me is to create a function that returns a local `MutableLiveData` and set its value whenever you need:

```
fun authTokenLiveData(): MutableLiveData<String?> {
    
    val tokenLiveData = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    
    // Do your logic here and post/set values to 
    // the MutableLiveData according to your accessing thread ...
    
    tokenLiveData.post(accountManager.myAuthToken())

    reutrn tokenLiveData
}
```

Observer:

```
accountViewModel.authTokenLiveData().observe(this) {
    toast("Token is $it")
    if(it == null) goToLogin()
}
```